# Special character matching in r using grep

Tags: r, design-patterns, matching

If I have a sentence separated by spaces

```
s<-("C java","C++ java")
grep("C",s)
```

gives output as
    [1] [2] 
while I only require 
[1] 
How to do that? ( I have used c\++ to identify c++ separately but matching with C gives [1] and [2] both as the output)

Answer (score 2):

If we want to match 1 only, then we can use the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string to denote that there are no characters after or before 'C'

```
grep("^C$",s)
#[1] 1
```

#### data

```
s<- c("C","C++","java")
```

Comment: yes that works but now I am having a sentence vector                           s<-("C java","C++ java")
grep("C",s)    and I want o/p as [1]

Comment: @ApoorvaSrivastava  Try with `grep("\\bC ", s)#
[1] 1`

Comment: @ApoorvaSrivastava  In the above case it is space after 'C' that we are matching, but if we use `\\bC\\b` it will also return the 2nd one as `\\b` is `(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))`.  If we want to go for the long way `grep("C(?:(?<![\\w+])(?=[\\w+])|(?<=[\\w+])(?![\\w+]))", s, perl = TRUE)` make sure that `+` is not included

Answer (score 0):

```
s<-c("C","C++","java")    
which(s %in% "C")
```

`grep()` gives a positive result for any match within a string